# Why doesn't Keras handle the difference between Theano and TF representations for images?

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras, theano

Why doesn't Keras handle the difference between Theano and Tensorflow representations for images with channels? For e.g., if you use Theano as the backend, them images are in the (*samples, color_depth, width, height*) form and if you use TF, then images are in the (*samples, width, height, color_depth*) format. Seems like Keras could just go with one or the other and then reformat the shape behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keras does work with only one representation.

By standard, it uses `channels_last`. 
A user can change it to `channels_first` if they like.

You can create a keras model and use it either with tensorflow or theano without changing anything about the model.

The file `keras.json` contains the standard definition:

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "image_data_format": "channels_last",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

The file can be found in `<user>\.keras\keras.json`

You can also override the standard setting by defining for each layer the parameter `data_format`. (See [here](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d)).

It's a good thing to avoid then using tensorflow or theano functions directly. For cases where it's necessary, try the [Keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/) functions.